# Gradle Download Task with Basic Auth behaves differently on GitHub Actions

Tags: gradle, github-actions, basic-authentication

I am using gradle with the Download Task provided by Michael Kraemer (see: https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task). The remote site requires HTTPS and a Basic Auth. Although I configured everything and the task works perfectly on my local machine, execution by the GitHub Actions on a ubuntu-linux runner behaves differently.

On my local machine, the request sent contains Basic Auth headers and the server response with a 302 redirect providing the expected download file. However, on the build server it turns out, that the Download Tasks downloads a HTML file. This is the typical response of the server application if one did not specify Basic Auth. So, I now assume that the GitHub runners omit the Basic Auth headers when the above gradle plugin spawns a http client / connection with Basic Auth.

Is anyone experiencing something alike? Is there a workaround for this situation? I cannot change the authentification method of the server where I am required to download the software from, so I'd be happy to get some support here. :-)

Here is the definition of the download task from my build.gradle.kts:

```
    tasks.register<Download>("download") {
        src(https://software.vendor.com/path/to/file)
        dest(file("${DOWNLOAD_FOLDER}/vendor-software-${VERSION}.zip"))
        username("USER")
        password("PASS")
        authScheme("Basic")
        overwrite(false)
        tempAndMove(true)
        onlyIfModified(true)
        useETag(true)
    }
```

**One addition**: It turns out that the fact that GitHub encodes all secrets values could be part of the issue. In fact, when I use the header configuration and configure the Basic Auth header directly, the process works:

```
    tasks.register<Download>("download") {
        src(https://software.vendor.com/path/to/file)
        dest(file("${DOWNLOAD_FOLDER}/vendor-software-${VERSION}.zip"))
        header("Authorization", "Basic VVNFUjpQQVNT")
        overwrite(false)
        tempAndMove(true)
        onlyIfModified(true)
        useETag(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect answer to the issue, nor does it explain why it occurs, but as an workaround, I uploaded a new secret that contains the Base64 encoded basic authorization header and use the header notation as mentioned above. This way, the download works, still it would be great to understand, why this happens.